# Unique entries in an array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have the following that stores the previous 10 URL's into a session:

```
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
//Insert Current URL in SESSION
       $CurrentPage = curPageURL();
       if(strpos($CurrentPage, '/products/'))
        {
        echo "<div class=\"title\">Recently viewed products</div>
<div id=\"recent\">";
       $_SESSION['pages'][] = $CurrentPage;
       if ( Count ( $_SESSION['pages'] ) > 10 )
        Array_Shift ( $_SESSION['pages'] );
```

How do I make sure only unique entries are stored?

Thanks,
B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just after

```
$_SESSION['pages'][] = $CurrentPage;
```

you need to add

```
$_SESSION['pages'] = array_unique($_SESSION['pages']);
```

Docs are available [here](http://uk.php.net/array_unique)

This method requires less processing, as it's a native function. Performing an 'if' on each item in the array could potentially be quite costly.

Comment: thats the road i was tring to go down - however I get:
Warning: array_unique() [function.array-unique]: The argument should be an array in
???

Comment: sorry, my bad. pasted the wrong code. It's amended now, the above should work

Answer (score 3):

instead of `$_SESSION['pages'][] = $CurrentPage` try `$_SESSION['pages'][$CurrentPage] = 1`

/edit: to keep items sorted, unset first:

```
 unset($_SESSION['pages'][$CurrentPage]);
 $_SESSION['pages'][$CurrentPage] = 1;
```

Comment: But this won't automatically push the other array items down. If they have visited this page 7 pages ago, the key for this item, which is probably what he using to output their page history, is still going to be whatever it was 7 pages ago, not moving it to the top or rearranging the other 6 pages, right?

Answer (score 3):

```
if(!in_array($CurrentPage, $_SESSION['pages']) {
    $_SESSION['pages'][] = $CurrentPage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) be of help?